# It works by creating a simple logical expression. The result is -1, 0, but is the logical expression correct?

Tags: fortran

Operating System : Windows 10
Compiler : X manager 6

Program code I wrote :

```
program nobody
implicit none
INTEGER :: M,N
REAL :: X,Y,Z,O

M = -5
N = 8
X = -3.56
Y = 0.0
Z = 44.7

O = X * Y < SQRT(Z)

print * , O

end program nobody
```

When calculated, it is 0 <6.68580586, so it becomes a logical expression. When printed, the result is -1.000000. If the logical expression is correct, is -1 output?

Comment: This is not Fortran: ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -std=f2008 rubbish.f90 
rubbish.f90:12:4:

 O = X * Y < SQRT(Z)
    1
Error: Can't convert LOGICAL(4) to REAL(4) at (1)

Comment: Are you saying that when you turn to Fortran, you get a comment error?

Comment: As the comment by Ian Bush points out, this is not valid Fortran but is accepted as an extension by some compilers (clearly yours does).  Do you want to know why you get `-1.0`, whether you'll always get `-1.0`, how to get some other value, or how to write correct Fortran?  (Or something else?)

Comment: I want to find the result of the above logical expression. How can I use the correct Fortran?

Comment: Declare `O` to be logical.

Comment: Brackets around X * Y, while possibly not strictly necessary, would help readability

Comment: Actually, don't declare `O` to be logical, use a different name which is easier to distinguish from `0`.

Comment: You possibly misunderstood High Performance Mark's (useful) comment.  You don't want to use the variable called `O` and you certainly don't want to call it `0`.  The comment was meant more to mean use `logical :: test` (or some other useful name) rather than `logical :: 0`.

Comment: "I get error" What error? Please edit the question

Comment: I rolled back your edit, it was absolutely nonsensical. You cannot have a variable named `0` (zero) as francescalus pointed out.

Comment: I don't think you could just tell me that you can't declare 0 as a variable without rolling back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### "The result is -1"

There is no standard numerical value of logical values. What happens here is that the compiler first converts the logical value to an integer, just by re-interpretting the bits and then converts the integer number to a real number.

In your compiler, a logical true value is such a value where all bits are 1. An integer number with such a bit pattern (hexadecimal FFFFFFFF) is -1. After a conversion to real you get -1.00000.

Other compilers will use the true logical value as all bits zero instead the lowest one which is set to 1. In that case this bit pattern corresponds to the integer number 1 and the real number would be 1.00000. If you use Intel Fortran, try setting `-standard-semantics` and observe what happens.

*(Note that there is no compiler called X manager 6. You might be using software called [Xmanager 6](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Remote-Utils/Xmanager.shtml) to connect to some remote Linux computer, but it is certainly not a Fortran compiler.)*

### "but is the logical expression correct?"

It is not correct standard Fortran but, as a non-standard vendor extension, it very likely does what you wanted if you really wanted an implicit conversion of the logical value to a real number. If you just wanted a **logical** value, and not a number, you must use a logical variable

```
logical ::logical_value

logical value = (X * Y) < SQRT(Z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortran (on ifort, both x86 and x64) represents logical .TRUE. as 0xFFFFFFFF and logical .FALSE. as 0x0. If you want to assign a logical value to REAL variable, it's first converted to INTEGER value (which is -1 for .TRUE. and 0 for .FALSE.) and then it's converted to REAL value. Take a quick look at this compiler output (I simplified the logical expression):

```
 O = M > N
 mov         eax,dword ptr [M]  
 mov         edx,dword ptr [N]  
 cmp         eax,edx  
 jg          MAIN+6Eh (0FB106Eh)  
 mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],0  
 jmp         MAIN+75h (0FB1075h)  
 mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],0FFFFFFFFh  
 mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8]  
 cvtsi2ss    xmm0,eax  
 movss       dword ptr [O],xmm0
```

The CVTSI2SS means "convert INTEGER(4) to REAL(4)". This conversion (INTEGER -> REAL) is the reason why you don't see a NaN output (0xFFFFFFFF is a NaN value in single precision, according to IEEE 754 floating point numbers standard).

Comment: @francescalus I wanted to say "represents", sorry.

Comment: No problem.  What do you mean by "Fortran represents"?  Do you mean a specific compiler/version?

Comment: I think it's quite general (using int32 for a representation of logical values) and you'll find this representation of LOGICALs in most compilers. Even when I tried compilation of this code on x64, LOGICALs were still represented as int32. I have seen this representation on most of languages. However, to make the explanation more clear, I added the compiler.